# Go doesn't recognize regexp

Tags: go

I need to add special characters (@#$%^&.?) to the oneof or use regexp, but regexp errors on execution is undefined. I am currently using, oneof=uppercase&lowercase&numeric. this validator would be checking if the passwords contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number and 1 special character.

Sample Code ==>

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type UserReg struct {
    Username        string `validate:"required,min=4,max=15"`
    Email           string `validate:"required,email"`
    Password        string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,eqfield=ConfirmPassword,oneof=uppercase&lowercase&numeric"`
    ConfirmPassword string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,oneof=uppercase&lowercase&numeric"`
}

type UserReg2 struct {
    Username        string `validate:"required,min=4,max=15"`
    Email           string `validate:"required,email"`
    Password        string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,eqfield=ConfirmPassword,regexp=^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&.?/]).$"`
    ConfirmPassword string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,regexp=^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&.?/]).$"`
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Start of working test w/o check for special characters")

    ut := UserReg{
        Username:        "Joe23",
        Email:           "Joe@joe.com",
        Password:        "Pa55w0rd",
        ConfirmPassword: "Pa55w0rd",
    }

    validate := validator.New()

    err := validate.Struct(ut)
    fmt.Println(err)

    fmt.Println("End of working test w/o check for special characters")

    fmt.Println("Start of failing test w/ check for special characters")

    ut2 := UserReg2{
        Username:        "Joe23",
        Email:           "Joe@joe.com",
        Password:        "Pa$$w0rd",
        ConfirmPassword: "Pa$$w0rd",
    }

    err2 := validate.Struct(ut2)
    fmt.Println(err2)

    fmt.Println("End of failing test w/ check for special characters")
}
```

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Changed original post deleting the code that was there and replacing it with a full example program

Answer (score 2):

After playing around I came up with by changing the line in UserReg to:

```
    Password        string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,eqfield=ConfirmPassword,oneof=uppercase&lowercase&numeric&@ # $ % ^ \& . ? \/"`
    ConfirmPassword string `validate:"required,min=8,max=20,oneof=uppercase&lowercase&numeric&@ # $ % ^ \& . ? \/"`
```

Comment: In the future, you can use something like https://regex101.com to test your regex.